# JQuery Simple Toggle Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function showSuccess() {
                $('#successDiv > p').empty().append("Saving the Device Whitelist was a success.<br />Server Resonse: Sucess");
                $('#successDiv').toggle().delay(4000).toggle();
            }

            $(function () {
                $('#successDiv').on('click', function () {
                    showSuccess();
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="successDiv" style="display:none">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>

        <input type="button" id="showSuccess" value="Show Success" />
    </body>
</html>
```

For some reason the toggle is not working...

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/js3E6/)

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: The div is meant to display for 4secs then go away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue: you bind click to wrong element; second: it's looks like you should set explicit timings when use `delay`:

```
function showSuccess() {
    $('#successDiv > p').empty().append("Saving the Device Whitelist was a success.<br />Server Resonse: Sucess");
    $('#successDiv').toggle(100).delay(4000).toggle(100);
}

$(function () {
    $('#showSuccess').on('click', showSuccess);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/js3E6/2/)

Upd: issue with timings is a jQuery restriction:

> Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will
>   not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not
>   use the effects queue.

(From `delay` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delay/))

Comment: Yeah thanks for that, is there a reason for having to set the toggle times when chaining?

Comment: This is jQuery requirement: >Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use the effects queue. (Got it [here](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)). I add this note to answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#successDiv').on('click', function () {
```

should be

```
 $('#showSuccess').on('click', function () {
```

and

```
 $('#successDiv').toggle().delay(4000).toggle();
```

should be

```
 $('#successDiv').show(0).delay(4000).hide(0);
```

here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L35rW/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example : http://jsfiddle.net/js3E6/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#showSuccess').on('click', function () {

        $('#successDiv > p').html("Saving the Device Whitelist was a success.<br />Server Resonse: Sucess");
        $('#successDiv').slideDown().delay(4000).slideUp();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you remove the last part `delay(4000).toggle();` it works. http://jsfiddle.net/582Z3/

```
$('#successDiv').toggle();
```

What do you wnat the delay to?

Btw, also change the id in the click event to `$('#showSuccess')`.